# Type check possible values for an interface property based on another property array values

Tags: typescript

Looking for a way to typecheck possible values in an interface based on another property array type values:

```js
export interface RootLayoutTab {
    id: string;
    title: string;
}

interface RootLayoutProps<T extends Array<RootLayoutTab>> {
    tabs: T;
    defaultTab: (T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never)['id'];
}

const tabs: RootLayoutTab[] = [
    { id: 'database', title: 'Database' },
    { id: 'gateways', title: 'Gateways' },
];

const props: RootLayoutProps<typeof tabs> = {
    tabs,
    defaultTab: 'database-test', 
// expected typecheck error due to valid values 'database' and 'gateways', but currently passes typecheck
};
```

Comment: I think you want a `const` assertion and `satisfies` instead of a type annotation, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpzl7w).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you so much for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the `tabs` variable as `RootLayoutTab[]`, then that's all the compiler will know about its type afterward.  Since the `id` property of `RootLayoutTab` is just `string`, then you've thrown away the information you need to restrict `defaultTab` to `"database" | "gateways"`.  So as a first step, let's *not* annotate the variable:

```
const tabs = [
  { id: 'database', title: 'Database' },
  { id: 'gateways', title: 'Gateways' },
];
// const tabs: {id: string; title: string}[]
```

This still isn't going to work, because the type inferred for `tabs` is equivalent to `RootLayoutTab[]`. TypeScript has no idea that you care about the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `id` properties, and so it infers `string` (usually people want `{a: "abc"}` to be inferred as type `{a: string}`).  The easiest way to tell TypeScript that you do care about such things is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const tabs = [
  { id: 'database', title: 'Database' },
  { id: 'gateways', title: 'Gateways' },
] as const;
/* const tabs: readonly [{
    readonly id: "database";
    readonly title: "Database";
}, {
    readonly id: "gateways";
    readonly title: "Gateways";
}] */
```

The `const` assertion says "I don't plan to make any changes at all to this value, so please infer the most specific type you can for it, including literal types".  The inferred type here is very close to what you want, although TypeScript tends to infer [`readonly` arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) and your types apparently require mutable arrays.  Let's loosen that restriction:

```
interface RootLayoutProps<T extends readonly RootLayoutTab[]> {
  tabs: T;
  defaultTab: T[number]['id'];
}
```

I widened `RootLayoutTab[]` to `readonly RootLayoutTab[]` (and, for good measure, changed your computation of `defaultTab` to just [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T` with `number` to get the element type, instead of using a more complex [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)).  Now we have enough for the rest of your code to function as desired:

```
const props: RootLayoutProps<typeof tabs> = {
  tabs,
  defaultTab: 'database-test', // error!
  //~~~~~~~~ <-- Type '"database-test"' is not 
  //assignable to type '"database" | "gateways"'
};
```

That looks good.

---

Still, you presumably want to know that `tabs` is a valid array of `RootLayoutTab` elements right at its declaration and not only later.  Right now if you make a mistake like

```
const tabs = [
  { id: 'database', titel: 'Database' }, // no error?!
  { id: 'gateways', title: 'Gateways' },
] as const;
```

there's no error inside `tabs`, and you have to wait until you define `props` to see the problem:

```
declare const props: RootLayoutProps<typeof tabs>; // error!
// --------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Property 'title' is missing in type '{ readonly id: "database"; readonly titel: "Database"; }'
// but required in type 'RootLayoutTab'.
```

Really you want to *check* `tabs` against `RootLayoutTab[]` without *widening* it to `RootLayoutTab[]`. To do that you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
const tabs = [
  { id: 'database', titel: 'Database' }, // error!    
  // -------------> ~~~~~ 
  // Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'titel' 
  // does not exist in type 'RootLayoutTab'. Did you mean to write 'title'?
  { id: 'gateways', title: 'Gateways' }, // error!
] as const satisfies RootLayoutTab[];
```

Now you get the error right on the source of the mistake, which makes it easier to fix:

```
const tabs = [
  { id: 'database', title: 'Database' },
  { id: 'gateways', title: 'Gateways' },
] as const satisfies RootLayoutTab[]; // okay
```

Looks good!

---

Note: the above works in TypeScript 5.3 due to a feature implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#55229](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/55229) where `[⋯] as const satisfies T[]` allows the `const`-asserted array literal to be inferred as a *mutable* tuple instead of the *readonly* tuple normally produced.  In TS5.2 and below, `[⋯] as const satisfies T[]` would be an error, and you'd have to change it to `[⋯] as const satisfies readonly T[]`.  It's not really a big deal either way, but this is easier, since now we can leave your definition of `RootLayoutProps` alone and still have it work:

```
interface RootLayoutProps<T extends RootLayoutTab[]> { ⋯ }

const tabs = [
  { id: 'database', title: 'Database' },
  { id: 'gateways', title: 'Gateways' },
] as const satisfies RootLayoutTab[]; // okay

const props: RootLayoutProps<typeof tabs> = {
  tabs,
  defaultTab: 'database-test', // error!
  //~~~~~~~~ <-- Type '"database-test"' is not 
  //assignable to type '"database" | "gateways"'
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=5.3.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgJQghgBlMBPCAVxgBVMAjOAbwFgAoORAEwC44AzjCjIA5gG4OXGAhgAbYPyEikEjgF8OyVBhx5CxMpRoAFKBDACAPLTihUSbgIJFSFanUYBtALoA+Fik4GEYBflpJTjhuYCwqOU8GcK8kKgBbBjQfLwByBG4cn0jNdg4ObAgkIWDQuABeOC8g5h5+HO5MEIZMAWAcgBpg2QU2gBFOxh6+uHV+5ta4HNFO4AB3CgEBoflFRYBxFfXyTZm59h84HrgKqvgBToQBdARgZwM3Y0TfSPLK6rBzJZ+O8jB4zBZrDByGBgBB0DUGAIAg02FEugIzlwYnEEvQkosOl0pgBaVBCLYAegpdig5igAEIglSAH6stmsuBWYnEuC0aF4HIAIkJk16pNeMEFOUQziQxDgTIpPQECFESEYCmCEGC-MWwom3V6grgAB84ILlqgjgIpRofux1WlXmA9HAAPIQwJRG7VdH1RpBLgtfJtEWGvqDGSoORjA1TaWzOBUuByml0gD8jKiQYWS0OGy2UZG+3zxwTmLgFyuPpg9qxwGwckwUDwNbgAIhwNcoNMgMh-LhCKR4iT1LQdKzXGT3Jns7n84Xc4C7JXrMVcHBMNg5EWRemjzgaUeKtUiCQOphixaLcw3Eqch3IfNYamgpHN7vSAf22AMfN4yJI0R3UHJ1wYGg4BbABHKgEBbbgzwvAUQXcGg8RyAA6Mp2BKDhHWdV0ACFgBgHQvS4Ns-QaJpsxYXMX16QtZF-WNAOmRNk3HaB6S4LhA1HOBFyXOAVwVWjkzdBgACsG3gORmKgTA5EPCg4HvHcBBhbAEHQHcAGs5VWc8Oy3GRXkGcD4ByKNf2lfjkzvV4U3lUBHngZAkMWFDPnQjC4FGfI4GMQ9gEwc8YG1VYRFQXdhj6dN+ODPhFktNYC0jOK2gOK0C1OASuIZIIq2cNt7hkJ4XjebtUK+IpsPrRtm1bP54BMsIXEMGrN37GFB3RPwR042luPXISxvG7ll1XdlsPUIA)